# Can I ko.observable a session variable?

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I have 2 simple aspx pages. On my default page, I have a simple label that's using ko.data-binding to a Session variable.

I thought if I change that variable KnockoutJS would update the user interface. When I click the button on sessionchanger page I changed the session variable that is being observed by ko. Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the HTML received by the browser, then you'll understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it because **asp.net rendering engine** simply pass **value** of `Session["target"]` and not any link to that variable, also your knockout code isn't well written, see **@Viktor Kukurba** answer to get clearer idea of how to use and apply data-binding.

To achieve desired result you could use one of techniques listed below:

**Preferable**

Use [WebSockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh969243.aspx) to notify your **"Default" page** about changing session variable by **"Session Changer"  page**. 
Take a look on tutorial[Building real-time web apps with WebSockets using IIS, ASP.NET and WCF](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/SAC-807T) to get practical knowledge of how apply that techniques.

**Workaround**

As workaround you could get quite similar to required behaviour after applying next steps:

1. Create **asp.net** http request handler which would return value of `Session["target"]` in json format.
2. Create javascript function (let's call it `refreshSessionTarger`), which would send [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request to newly created asp.net http handler and update value of observable variable ( so knockout would reflect to that change, but note that you have to add ko data-binding properly).
3. Put `refreshSessionTarger` function created in step 2 into [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function as callback and set interval of how often  in milliseconds `refreshSessionTarger` shall be executed.

   ```
   function refreshSessionTarger(){
   // perform ajax request and update variable which holds session target
   };

   var delay = 5000;
   setInterval(refreshSessionTarger, delay)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change value of `status` property of `viewModel` instance to reflect changes on ui.

```
var vm  =  new viwModel;
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.status('new value');
```

You bind `vm` object to `body` not session object. You just use session object to initialize `vm.status` property.

So, you can't set new value in `vm.status` from the other page.
To be able to track it you should use client-server communication. It can be [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) with polling functionality or [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket). So, you should check or listen server side and if any changes occur you can update `vm.status` property and after that it will reflect ui as you expect.

Comment: This completely misses the point of the question. OP is wondering why a browser does not automatically re-render a piece of server-side code.

Comment: As I understood, problem was that change of session value did not reflect change on view. Maybe you are right it could be just misunderstanding